# Ms Access Query

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables with the following data
Main Table:

```
R-1,F-2,3
R-1,F-1,5
R-1,F-2,6
R-1,F-3,1
```

Second sub table is

```
F-2,3
F-1,4
F-4,5
```

I need to write a query which results in

```
R-1,F-2,(3+3)
R-1,F-1,(5+4)
R-1,F-2,(6+3)
R-1,F-3,1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple join on F-column:

```
select T1.R, T1.F, T1.Num+Nz(T2.Num, 0) as Num
from T1 left join T2 on T2.F = T1.F
```